# Focus Follows Mouse on MacOS

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur

PROBLEM: how to implement **focus follow mouse for all windows / apps on MacOS**?

CONTEXT: terminal commands such as "defaults write com.apple.terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string true" implement the desired behavior ONLY for terminal windows.

SIMILAR POST: [Implement "Mouse Follows Focus" on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230479/implement-mouse-follows-focus-on-macos)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the answer: https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise
Works perfectly.

For the precise, classic behaviour of "focus follows mouse", without raising the window, it must be compiled with the suggested flags

```
make CXXFLAGS="-DOLD_ACTIVATION_METHOD -DEXPERIMENTAL_FOCUS_FIRST" && make install
```

and then run with the options:

```
/Applications/AutoRaise.app/Contents/MacOS/AutoRaise delay=0 focusDelay=1
```

Comment: What do "the window" and "it" refer to in the sentence 'For the precise, classic behaviour of "focus follows mouse", without raising the window, it must be compiled with the suggested flags'? The only 'make' command I'm familiar with is for automating build processes in software development. I have no idea what this answer is talking about.

Comment: "it" refers to the tool AutoRaise, which must be compiled with command in the answer.
make is a tool for automated building and the "flags" mentioned are just parameters passed to make (i.e., CXXFLAGS="-DOLD_ACTIVATION_METHOD -DEXPERIMENTAL_FOCUS_FIRST") to configure the build process.

Comment: @Addlai, you OK there, bud? ;)

Comment: AutoRaise now has a built-in option to focus on hover (with option to set delay as well) without raising the window

Answer (score 3):

[Yabai Window Manager](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) also has an autofocus implementation, along with window borders and other features. It may be overkill for this specific use case, but for people looking for this feature because they came from another TWM it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Note for users with Case Sensitive file systems (like many of us) the command should be
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string YES
note the "T" in terminal.  Otherwise terminal will ignore the setting.  Also in Monterey I used Xcode to edit the plist and found that  FocusFollowsMouse was already present but as a boolean and not a string.  The entry must have type string with value YES to work properly.

Once the above changes were made terminal worked with FocusFollowsMouse on my new M1 MacBook Pro with Monterey.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I use successfully on Mojave and Big Sur on an M1 Mac:

defaults write com.apple.terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string true

Comment: This doesn't work for all applications but I've found the answer: https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise